# Adding unique identifier with Fluent API

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, fluent

I'm using a model which I have no control over, which I am saving instances of in a SQL database.

I'm using Fluent API to add a primary key to an attribute in this model

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().HasKey(d => d.DocumentId);
```

`Message` looks like this:

```
[Required]
public Guid DocumentId { get; set; }
[Required]
public int Size { get; set; }
public string SenderId { get; set; }
```

However it's entirely possible to receive two `Message`'s with the same `DocumentId`. Normally I'd have SQL add a unique identifier when saving using something like `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`, but since I don't have control of `Message`, how would I handle this?

Any hints greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily EF Core allows you to define and use [Shadow property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) as PK.

For instance, the following fluent configuration will create identity column named "Id" and use it as PK:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
    .Property<int>("Id")
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
    .HasKey("Id");
```

`ValueGeneratedOnAdd` and `HasKey` in this case are redundant, because property named "Id" by convention is PK and `int` type PKs by convention are auto generated, but I've added them for completeness.

But please note that working with the shadow PK will be harder though. Adding is easy, but read, update and delete operations will be problematic. `EF.Property` method can be used inside the LINQ queries to refer to the shadow PK, but in general you'd need some secondary criteria in case you want to update or delete a record.

Comment: But wouldn't that override `DocumentId` when storing then?

Comment: Sorry, can't follow, could you paraphrase? The way I understand the question, you wanted the equivalent of `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` w/o using data annotations, which I think the answer and the related link are covering.

Comment: I see now. What I was going for was if it is possible to use Fluent to create a new column with a unique identifier similarly to what `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` would be used for, but not on `DocumentId`, as I want to be able to store multiple identical `DocumentId`'s.