# Entity Framework - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'"

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, foreign-keys

Using MySql DB and Entity Framework, when im trying insert a data that contais a lists of child data i recive this error: InnerException = {"Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'"}

Here is a image of my tables: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAnVy.png

This is my Models:

```
public class Etapa 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [Column("ativo", TypeName = "bit")]
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    [Column("finalizadora", TypeName = "bit")]
    public bool Finalizadora { get; set; }

    public List<EtapaVinculada> ListaEtapaVinculada { get; set; }
}
```

```
[Table("etapa_vinculada")]
public class EtapaVinculada 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("id_etapa_pai")]
    public int EtapaPaiId { get; set; }

    public Etapa EtapaPai { get; set; }

    [Column("id_etapa_filha")]
    public int EtapaFilhaId { get; set; }

    public Etapa EtapaFilha { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

Etapa's contexts is here:

```
public class ContextoEtapa : Contexto
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Etapa>().HasMany(x => x.ListaEtapaVinculada).WithOne(y => y.EtapaPai).HasForeignKey(x => x.EtapaPaiId);
    }

    public async Task Adicionar(Etapa registro)
    {
        await AddAsync(registro);
        await SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Filling manually the tables in DB, when i debug my context i can see my Etapa object is filled and the property ListEtapaVinculada is filled too, correctly.

The problem happens when the Etapa object filled with its list of EtapaVinculada is going to be inserted into the database using the Add method. It seems to me that I did some wrong mapping, because it gives the impression that Entity tries to insert 2x the Etapa record in a row, falling into the duplicate key error.

The auto increment is working. If i try to save a object like this:

```
 {
        Etapa etapa = new Etapa();
        etapa.Descricao = "test";
        etapa.Ativo = true;
        etapa.Finalizadora = true;
        etapa.ListaEtapaVinculada = new List<EtapaVinculada>(); // Without itens

        using (var context = new ContextoEtapa())
        {
            await context.Etapa.AddAsync(etapa);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

But, if i do something like this:

```
 {
        Etapa etapaFilha = null;

        using (var context = new ContextEtapa())
        {
            etapaFilha = await context.Etapa.Where(x => x.Id == 666).First();
        }

        Etapa etapa = new Etapa();
        etapa.Descricao = "test";
        etapa.Ativo = true;
        etapa.Finalizadora = true;
        etapa.ListaEtapaVinculada = new List<EtapaVinculada>();

        EtapaVinculada etapaVinculada = new EtapaVinculada();
        etapaVinculada.EtapaPaiId = etapa.Id;
        etapaVinculada.EtapaPai = etapa;
        etapaVinculada.EtapaFilhaId = etapaFilha.Id;
        etapaVinculada.EtapaFilha = etapaFilha;

        etapa.listaEtapaVinculada.Add(etapaVinculada);

        using (var context = new ContextoEtapa())
        {
            await context.Etapa.AddAsync(etapa);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

Now i got the erros of duplicate Key. Its seems to me that EF is trying to insert 2x Etapa object, when the correct is insert Etapa, then insert all itens of ListaEtapaVinculada.

Comment: Thanks for translating; I vote to re-open now

Comment: You have to add the 'auto increment' part to your logic. This depends on EF version and used db provider. Also, EF's and EF core's behaviour are different. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49799970/adding-unique-identifier-with-fluent-api) are some examples for EF core, fluent api, sql - to get your head around it. Be aware, the examples are for `SQL` not `mySql`.

Comment: Kind of off-topic: [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is way better, if your classes, properties, methods are written in english. Alternativly, there is a [spanish version](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) of SO available, too. Buena suerte!

Comment: I edited to explain a little more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is when trying to assign an instance of the object and an id at the same time, try commenting on the following line of code:

```
 {
    Etapa etapaFilha = null;

    using (var context = new ContextEtapa())
    {
        etapaFilha = await context.Etapa.Where(x => x.Id == 666).First();
    }

    Etapa etapa = new Etapa();
    etapa.Descricao = "test";
    etapa.Ativo = true;
    etapa.Finalizadora = true;
    etapa.ListaEtapaVinculada = new List<EtapaVinculada>();

    EtapaVinculada etapaVinculada = new EtapaVinculada();
    // etapaVinculada.EtapaPaiId = etapa.Id; // this is asigned when asign to collection and savechanges

    // etapaVinculada.EtapaPai = etapa;

    etapaVinculada.EtapaFilhaId = etapaFilha.Id; // 

    // etapaVinculada.EtapaFilha = etapaFilha; this is duplicate

    etapa.listaEtapaVinculada.Add(etapaVinculada);

    using (var context = new ContextoEtapa())
    {
        await context.Etapa.AddAsync(etapa);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```